# Fermi-Walker transportation

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

Consider a timelike curve C in a curved spacetime with unit tangent vector $u^\alpha$. A vector $v^\alpha$ is said to be [Fermi-Walker transported](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Walker_transport) along C if:
$$
u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha v^\beta = u^\beta A^\gamma v_\gamma - u^\gamma A^\beta v_\gamma
$$
with $A^\gamma = u^\alpha \nabla _\alpha u^\gamma$ the acceleration of $u^\alpha$.

How can I show that the tangent vector $u^\alpha$ is always Fermi-transported (obeys the equation above) along $C$ (any timelike curve)?

Analytical solution:

First we substitute $u^\mu=v^\mu$ which gives the following terms:

LHS:
$$
u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha u^\beta = A^\beta
$$
RHS:
$$
u^\beta A^\gamma u_\gamma-u^\gamma A^\beta u_\gamma=u^\beta u_\gamma A^\gamma+A^\beta
$$
(using the fact that $u^\gamma u_\gamma = -1$ for tangent vetorrs on a time-like curve)
$$
=u^\beta u^\alpha(\nabla_\alpha u^\gamma) u_\gamma    +A^\beta
$$
substituting the acceleration formula
$$
=\frac{1}{2}u^\beta u^\alpha (\nabla_\alpha u^\gamma u_\gamma)    +A^\beta
$$
using the multiplication rule for differentiation
$$
=\frac{1}{2}u^\beta u^\alpha (\nabla_\alpha (-1))    +A^\beta=A^\beta
$$
Hence the tangent vector $u^\alpha$ is always Fermi-transported!

Comment: I suppose you could see if they satisfy the teleparallism within general relativity?

Comment: Could you explain that in an answer please?

Comment: I would imagine it would be a fairly easy exercise to do, if you look into it. By the way my suggestion was just that, just a suggestion, I wouldn't know if there was a more standard way to approach your question.

Comment: Have you tried plugging in $v=u$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can plug in $v=u$ in the condition for Fermi-Walker transport and get

$$u^\alpha\nabla_\alpha u^\beta = u^\beta A^\gamma u_\gamma - u^\gamma A^\beta u_\gamma$$

Notice that the left hand side is exactly $A^\beta$, then use the fact that $u^\alpha$ is a unit vector tangent to a timelike curve, so that $u^\alpha u_\alpha = -1$, to take care of the second term in the right hand side.

The only thing left to do is to show that $A^\gamma u_\gamma=0$. (Hint: start from $u^\alpha u_\alpha = -1$ and take a covariant derivative)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have updated my question with a full derivation.